# How to print Silently in CefSharp

Tags: cefsharp

I have seen several post regarding this silent printing but no one give any answer can some tell me that is it possible to print directly to default printer without showing print dialog or option like kiosk???

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#printing My previous answer has been deleted without comment. Nothing has changed,  there is no direct support for silent printing.